# Software for Floor Plan of School

Tags: gratis

What is some free software that I can use to make a 2D floor plan of my school and save it as JPEG OR PNG, etc.

I would prefer the software to be simple to use and not too complicated.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! [What's "best" is always subjective](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/157/185): *one man's owl is another man's nightingale.* Better describe what would makes this software *fitting best for you* – which then enables us to give fitting recommendations. See [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) for more hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience building 2d room drawings, after a couple I decide I really wanted a 3D model.  If you later decide to make the transition to 3d  like I did, sketchup will really make the transition easier.

There is some learning curve, but the free version of [SketchUp](http://www.sketchup.com/) was one of the easiest I encountered.

Sketchup now comes with Sketchup Layout which is 100% 2D and should be everything you need. Goto *File* and *export* and you can save it as an image, like PNG.

Comment: Thank you! However, I really need a 2D floor plan software.

Comment: @TomHogan  Sketchup comes with Sketchup Layout it is 100% 2D.  Goto File and export and you can save it as an image, like PNG.

Comment: @TomHogan      Well, if you used my idea, please mark mine as the answer.  Thanks

Comment: Done. I appreciate it.